# Visa application Return shipping from UKVI scanning hub, New York

Tags: visas, paperwork, online-resources, applications, vfs-global

Does anyone have experience purchasing a return shipping label from the visa scanning hub in New York? The VFS Global website does not have that location as an option. I am not using a premium visa application location. Just mailing it in myself after my biometrics appointment.

Also, I keep running into a section where it wants me to upload all of my documents before being able to purchase my shipping label (even for a visa services location) I am tempted to purchase a shipping label from the UPS site but the VFS website says it **must be a VFS label.**
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've emailed VFS multiple times now.

Comment: I am facing the exact same situation. How did you resolve it? I am going to be purchasing my own UPS shipping label and just pray it comes back to me. Please let me know if you found a better solution

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you do not need to purchase the shipping label from VFS unless you wish to use their premium service. You are free to use a pre-paid, self-addressed UPS shipping label for passport/document return. Quoting from [VFS FAQ](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/us/en/how-to-apply):

> ## 8. Document return
>
> Customers who attend a Premium Application Centre, will have their passport returned to them by courier following the decision on their application, as part of the Bronze, Silver, Gold or Settlement Package purchased.
>
> Customers who visit an Application Support Center for their biometric appointment are advised to use one of the [UPS courier services](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/us/en/premium-services/super-priority-visa) offered by VFS Global. If you choose not to purchase this service from us, you may use a courier company of your choice to send your passport/documents to the UKVI Visa Processing Hub, but you **must** provide a pre-paid, self-addressed **UPS shipping label** for passport/document return.

This seems to be backed up by this other similar question: [How to generate UK Visitor Visa Shipping label for VFS Global](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129149/how-to-generate-uk-visitor-visa-shipping-label-for-vfs-global)