# How to generate UK Visitor Visa Shipping label for VFS Global

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, tourist-visas, vfs-global

After my biometrics was done, I was handed a document that provided the list of supporting documents that I need to mail in.
The document clearly mentions

> A UPS return shipping label purchase using this link:
>   www.vfsglobal.co.uk/ShoppingCart/Pages/Authorization.aspx

I registered for the Chicago location, but I am unable to figure out if one needs to purchase the pricier Gold/Silver/Bronze options for just generating the shipping labels. 
I went ahead and purchased the Bronze option, but have not received any email with the shipping labels as the site indicated.

Some other answers indicate that creating a UPS label from UPS site and mailing the application is also possible. In that case, VFS seems completely unnecessary.

Is VFS an optional step in the process or is it mandatory? Which of the various options should one select if all I want are the shipping labels?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, were you able to download the shipping label or did you purchase directly from UPS ?

Comment: The site is not very user friendly. I called the number that was provided in the document that is handed to you after biometric recording. They advised that there is no need to visit local VFS office. So I went to UPS, got the return shipping label generated by UPS store and sent it with the passport & other docs. received my visa yesterday.

Comment: @Tathagata did you just creat a normal ups return label or should we create pickup aswell.

Comment: @cris normal return label, did sure what pickup option is though.

Comment: Hey @Tathagata what address did u send the passport and document to, how do I find this address. I am in San Fran, CA.

Answer (score 3):

VFS premium service is option, but you need to purchase the return label through the site. They call it premium service also, which is confusing. 
If you buy the round trip - you will just have to drop it in the nearest UPS.

Comment: I was able to purchase the return shipping label at the UPS store and did not require doing it thru their site.